# how would I knock out an array subscript from a string in PHP with preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have an array coming in from a textarea, it's a simple array of arrays:

```
$l[0] = array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
$l[1] = array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
```

and so on. I've got everything off except the numerals and commas but I want to remove the array subscripts leaving just the data - I'm not an expert on regular expressions, what would be the best way to do it?

thanks :)

Comment: you want just the data? so here you want just 0,0,0,0,0,0,0... etc. right?

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match('/array\(([\d,]+)\)/',$input_string,$matches);
//0,0,0,0,0,0... in $matches[1];
$data = explode(',',$matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

`preg_match_all("#array\((\d,?)\)#iU", $text, $results);`

you could then grab the data from the results array

```
<?php
$text = '$l[0] = array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
$l[1] = array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
$l[2] = array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);';

$results = array();
preg_match_all('#array\( ((?:\d,?)*) \)#x', $text, $matches);
for( $i = 0, $L = sizeof($matches[1]); $i < $L; $i++)
{
    $results[] = explode(',', $matches[1][$i]);
}
print_r($results);
```

Comment: brilliant, thank you (to both of you I intend to upvote both of you) but why is it only returning the first two rows of the array?

Comment: I'm sorry, hackartist gave you a better solution, since preg_match_all would remember only the last digit in each of the arrays. I've edited the answer.